# regex in mySQL and MariaDB give different results

Tags: mysql, regex, mariadb, compatibility

I am migrating my MariaDB to MySQL and have come across differences.

I have a very simple query that produces results (197) in Maria DB but Zero in mySQL can anyone help?

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT title FROM films where title REGEXP 'The \\w{4}[^\\s]*\\b'
```

The database is exactly the same (exported from MariaDB into MySQL with no issues).

Comment: What is the MySQL version?

Comment: Check the REGEXP syntax for the two versions -- they may be different.  MySQL made an incompatible change recently.

Comment: thanks guys, @WiktorStribiżew the mySQL is
5.7.32 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Protocol version: 10
Server charset: cp1252 West European (latin1) and the phpMyAdmin is Ver 4.9.5


I've tried a number of variations on the syntax (escapes/non-escapes etc) but I can't seem to find a combination that gives the correct result on both. Do you know where  I would find information about the 'incompatible changes' to MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL 5.7, you have to use the POSIX-like regex library and use

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT title FROM films where title REGEXP 'The [[:alnum:]_]{4}[^[:space:]]*[[:>:]]'
```

Also, note that the regex matching here will be case insensitive, if you need to make `The` only match `The` and not `THE`, you need to add the `BINARY` keyword after `REGEXP`.

Here,

- `[[:alnum:]_]{4}` - `\w{4}` - four word chars, letters, digits or underscores
- `[^[:space:]]*` - `\S*` - zero or more non-whitespace chars
- `[[:>:]]` - `\b(?!\w)` - a right-hand (trailing) word boundary

Comment: Thank you @Wiktor Stribiżew I have re-run the query on both DBs and the results match up now, the bad news is that I'm going to have to redo all my regexs to fit POSIX!!

Comment: Hi Wiktor, I did upvote it but I haven't got 15 rep points so it won't show ;)